Как решить ошибку с кодировкой в Swagger + Asp net core
При запуске с контейнера то начинаются траблы с кодировкой в верхней части свагера.

Второй скрин

Вся остальная документация отображается нормально. Все методы описаны на русском языке и проблем нет.
